# Need help finding intersection of a hyperbola and a circle

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

```
Clear[y, z, x, eq1, eq2]

eq1 = (x^2/400) + (y^2/256) == 1

eq2 = (x^2/144) + (-(y^2/289)) == 1

ContourPlot[Evaluate[{eq1, eq2}], {x, -60, 60}, {y, -60, 60}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Im trying too plot them and find the intersection btwn these two functions(i need to mark the intersection by a dot)

My teacher does this by zooming in on the graph, but i find this way too difficult. From zooming in how can you extract the exact values of the intersection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections ``

```
cp = ContourPlot[Evaluate[{eq1, eq2}], {x, -60, 60}, {y, -60, 60}];

intersections = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[cp, Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> False]
```

> ```
> {{-14.3143, -11.0858}, 
>  {-14.3143, 11.0858}, 
>  {14.3143, -11.0858},
>  {14.3143, 11.0858}}
> ```

```
Show[cp, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point @ intersections}]]
```

[image]

#### `MeshFunctions` + `Mesh` + `MeshStyle`

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[{eq1, eq2}], {x, -60, 60}, {y, -60, 60}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, Evaluate[eq1[[1]] - eq2[[1]]]], 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]
```

[image]

#### `ImplicitRegion` + `Region` + `Show`

```
{ir1, ir2, ir12} = ImplicitRegion[#, {{x, -60, 60}, {y, -60, 60}}] & /@ 
   {eq1, eq2, And[eq1, eq2]}; 

Show[MapThread[Region[#, BaseStyle -> #2] &][{{ir1, ir2, ir12}, 
    {Blue, Orange, Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}}],
  Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

#### `ImplicitRegion` + `RegionPlot`

```
RegionPlot[{ir1, ir2, ir12}, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]] /. p_Point :> {Red, p}
```

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: @kglr Thanks for the alternative solution! Where did you find the option ` Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> False`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, ``Options[Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections]`` gives ``{Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> True, Method -> Automatic}``. With the default setting we get 5 points (I think it includes self-intersection of the blue ellipse); so had to try `False`:)

Comment: @kglr Thanks, very tricky!

Answer (score 5):

Why not `Solve` for the intersections explicitly?

```
intersections = {x, y} /. Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {x, y}]
(* {{-60 Sqrt[545/9529],-(1088/Sqrt[9529])},{-60 \
Sqrt[545/9529],1088/Sqrt[9529]},{60 \
Sqrt[545/9529],-(1088/Sqrt[9529])},{60 \
Sqrt[545/9529],1088/Sqrt[9529]}} *)
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[{eq1, eq2}], {x, -60, 60}, {y, -60, 60},
 AspectRatio -> Full,
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[intersections]}]
```

[image: Intersections highlighted]

Comment: thank you, can you also give me an idea of what function to use to find the area inside the curves?

Comment: @Aran Perhaps `reg = ImplicitRegion[(x^2/400) + (y^2/256) <= 1 && (x^2/144) + (-(y^2/289)) >= 1, {x, y}]; RegionMeasure[reg]`? (You can view the shape of the region with `RegionPlot[reg]`.)

Answer (score 5):

You are almost there. Do the following. This:

```
eq1 = (x^2/400) + (y^2/256) == 1;

eq2 = (x^2/144) - (y^2/289) == 1;

sl = Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {x, y}]

(* {{x -> -60 Sqrt[545/9529], 
  y -> -(1088/Sqrt[9529])}, {x -> -60 Sqrt[545/9529], 
  y -> 1088/Sqrt[9529]}, {x -> 60 Sqrt[545/9529], 
  y -> -(1088/Sqrt[9529])}, {x -> 60 Sqrt[545/9529], 
  y -> 1088/Sqrt[9529]}} *)
```

gives you the solution. Then this:

```
Show[{
  ContourPlot[Evaluate[{eq1, eq2}], {x, -60, 60}, {y, -60, 60}],
  Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.015], Point[{x, y}]}] /. sl
  }]
```

plots it together with the intersection points. It returns the following:

[image]

Have fun!